# Lightweight function so an array of images cycles at random?

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble with writing a specific set of functions. I'm working on a visual sponsor bar for a responsive site. I have about 20 sponsor logos, divided into 5 divs, that I need to cycle at random. The piece of code I've started with works seamlessly if there are only 2 images in each div.

The images fade-in and fade-out at random; however, I need the function to do more than a flip-flop effect. In short, I need to create an array of rotator images for each div, then write a function to select one at random, turn any of the visible ones in that array off, and then fade the selected image in.

I've gone over and over this, and found code that works if the images are laid out in list format, but I need the images to float and wrap when responding to browser window size. Any help (and explanation) would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Link to the whole fiddle is below, but the first (of 5) divs look like this:

```
  <div class="rotator">
    <img src="http://www.fourtownfair.com/images/sponsors/agway.png" class="rotator-image" />
    <img src="http://www.fourtownfair.com/images/sponsors/robertrookey.png" class="rotator-image"/>
    <img src="http://www.fourtownfair.com/images/sponsors/fairviewfarms.png" class="rotator-image" />
    <img src="http://www.fourtownfair.com/images/sponsors/redrobin.png" class="rotator-image" />
</div>

<div class="rotator">
    <img src="http://www.fourtownfair.com/images/sponsors/equestriancollection.png" class="rotator-image" />
    <img src="http://www.fourtownfair.com/images/sponsors/salmonbrook.png" class="rotator-image" />
    <img src="http://www.fourtownfair.com/images/sponsors/smyth.png" class="rotator-image" />
    <img src="http://www.fourtownfair.com/images/sponsors/conlinfarm.png" class="rotator-image" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {

    //Timeout are called once and only once, you need to use Interval to repeat the call :-)  
    $(document).ready( function() { 
        //Interval with millisecond delay, 2000 = every 2 seconds, always divide by 1000 to get the time.
        setInterval(function(){rotateImages();}, 2000); 
    });

    //Breaking this function out, to make the interval statement more readable
    var rotateImages = function() {

        //Another thing I do to enhance readability, break the collection into a variable
        var rotatorArray = $(".rotator");

        //We've got the array of rotator blocks, select a random one by length (out of 5 in this case)
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * rotatorArray.length);

        //If the topmost randomly selected image is hidden, fade in, if it's visible, fade out
        if($(rotatorArray[rand].children[0]).css('display') == "none")
        {
            $(rotatorArray[rand]).children(".rotator-image").fadeIn();
        }
        else
        {
            $(rotatorArray[rand]).children(".rotator-image").fadeOut();
        }
    };
});
```

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/amandabeau/8Y7NM/5/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have over thought this (if I understand correctly) can you not just do this: http://jsfiddle.net/3tEJA/

```
function animate() {
    var max = $(".rotator img").length;
    $(".rotator img").eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*max)).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000,function() {
    animate();
  });
}
animate();
```

Comment: We both made the same mistake, we used Math.round instead of Math.floor. This leads to a problem where it tries to load an image that is not even there (4 images are indexed 0,1,2,3, while Math.round could return 4)

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeImages() {
    $('.rotator').each(function() {
        var currentImages = $(this).find('img')
        var number = Math.round(Math.random() * currentImages.length());
        currentImages.addClass('hidden');
        currentImages.eq(number).removeClass('hidden');
    });
}
```

and then you could use css3 transition to obtain the transition effect, for example:

```
.rotator img {
    opacity: 1
    transition: opacity 500ms ease;
}

.rotator img.hidden {
    opacity: 0
}
```

This implies that on page load all the images but one have the "hidden" class applied to them.

I haven't tested it but I'm quite confident that it should work.
I suggest you use css3 transition instead of the animate method as it is more performant. On older browser you will still see the images change, you'll just lose the fade thing